# Unable to dynamically change panel background image for IE, Chrome & Safari in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have an EXTJS panel as desktop background. I have added some code to dynamically change the background image. In Firefox it is working well but it is not working in any of other browsers.

```
var panelbg = Ext.getCmp('windowarea').body;
var tree = Ext.getCmp('desktoptree');
if (tree.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) 
{
    var selectedNode = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    var nodeid = selectedNode[0].data.id;
    var demo = "Data/wall/"+nodeid+".jpg";
    panelbg.setStyle('background-image','url('+demo+')');
    panelbg.setStyle('background-size','cover');
}
```

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head, but does this require the JS versions of style attributes, e.g., 'backgroundImage', backgroundSize'?

Comment: I can't test it now, but u can try with applyStyles() instead of setStyle()

Answer (score 0):

To change the background image of the panel try using setBodyStyle:

```
var panelbg = Ext.getCmp('windowarea');
var demo = "Data/wall/"+nodeid+".jpg";
panelbg.setBodyStyle('background:url(' + demo + ')');
```

I have a small sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/d9zQc/3/

I've done some testing in IE10, Firefox 21 and Chrome 26 and all work ok.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Just to make sure when you get your panel (panelbg) use Ext.getCmp('windowarea') without the .body at the end. I've updated my post and fiddle above to reflect that.